# jQuery click on iphone event not working?

Tags: jquery, iphone, select, mobile, click

Help I create a function in a jQuery where in the select button where click the background will change it's working on desktop but in mobile device its not anyone can help me please thanks.

Here is my code so far.

```js
$('.changeBg').click(function () { //better use change evenet
  $(this).toggleClass('BgColor');
});
```

```css
.changeBg {
  background-color:#fff;
}
.BgColor {
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="contact" class="changeBg">
  <option value="">Change!</option>
  <option value="">Changes!</option>
</select>
```

P.S I try to use `cursor: pointer;` CSS still not working

Comment: Try the `focus` event instead...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.changeBg').on('click',function () { 
   $(this).toggleClass('BgColor');
});
```